# Ensure the Last Character in a RichEdit control is Visible

Tags: c, winapi

Text is disappearing from the bottom of a `RichEdit` control window and I'd like to ensure the bottom character is always visible. Obviously, I could manually scroll to the bottom, but I'd like to do it under software control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the EM_SCROLLCARET message.  Position the caret first, GetWindowTextLength() and EM_SETSEL.

Comment: I didn't even have a caret set up (it's not an editor, its just a display) but I can look that all up.